# Do i need redux to integrate laravel api with react native cli

Tags: react-native, react-redux, laravel-api

Im am trying to integrate laravel login api with react native cli front end .Do i have to use redux ? And how to integrate it.

Answer (score 0):

its not necessary to use redux for integration of api you can use fetch or axios to request the server and then you can store data into `AsyncStorage` or `ContextApi`.if you want to go with redux then you have to install couple of libs

> "react-redux"
> "redux"
> "redux-logger"
> "redux-persist"
> "redux-thunk"

you can visit this [link](https://enappd.com/blog/redux-in-react-native-app/92/) for proper guide how to integrate redux